# How to rig a "cartoonish" style mouth that doesn't affect the rest of the face?

Tags: rigging

I'm modelling the character *Robotboy* from the cartoon, and personally I feel like it just might be my best model yet. However, I was attempting to rig the mouth and eventually the eyes, and it wasn't going exactly the way I wanted it to. Here's pictures of it before I posed the mouth, and after: [image: Before]

[image: After]

This is clearly not the look I'm trying to achieve. The creases around the mouth are not wanted, and I feel like it would look much better without the creases there. I also want the mouth to freely move to any location on the face, while still tracking on the surface of the face. Basically, something like this (I hope it doesn't look too confusing):
[image]
I've seen this done with Minecraft Blender animations, but I myself do not know how to approach this problem (I'm particularly new to this kind of stuff). Any advice for making this type of a facial rig would be appreciated, as I will be using this kind for animations in the future (it'd also be cool if I was offered a solution to make the eyes act the same at the mouth with the tracking and such, however I do not really need it once I have a solution for the mouth :D).

[image]

Comment: are you sure that you want to model the mouth, rather than project an image on the face, which would mean using for example the UV Warp modifier? In the case you'd like to model I guess you need to have a good topology

Comment: No because I intend to add teeth to the model later on (not cartoonish type, I'm literally gonna model them). I do not want a flat image as I wouldn't be able to add the teeth the way I want. Edit: oop sry I didn't see your last sentence ^^" What do you mean by good topology?

Comment: good topology: that would be able to follow this kind of deformation  ;)  please show your wireframe

Comment: Ok, I have added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your topology is not good for a head, basically you've kept the topology of a UV sphere, it won't help to deform properly, what you need to do is create a kind of topology that follows the face features (found on google, from 3D artist Israel Audelo "izzy"):

[image]

See how the topology rotates concentrically around the mouth. As your character is even simpler and the expression more exagarate you should do the same with no more edge loops than necessary:

[image]

Comment: I got close to the diagram you gave me, but I'm assuming things would've been far easier if I had initially had a good topology planned out beforehand. I'll get back to you once I try re-rigging it. Also, thanks, I now know what to focus on as I continue to learn Blender =)

Comment: I'm not saying that you need to stick to what I show, it's a quick drawing of how it should look  ;)

Comment: Yeah, don't think I can anyways. Thank you!

Comment: Still haven't tried it, but I was looking at this free mc rig someone made and the mouth behaved exactly I wanted my model to work. The topology on the mouth was similar to what you showed me as well. I believe you may have answered my problem :D